# Axapta , EP installation with MOSS 2010 error

Tags: sharepoint-2010, moss, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I am I have installed AX 2009, SP1, RU7 and compiled and synchronized the application. Now I am trying to install EP with MOSS 2010. For that I have used the hotfix KB 2278963 and pasted the dll files in the AX installer as per instructions.

Then I created a site with port 1024 through MOSS central admin web page.

Now when I have completed  the  EP setup, at last it is  showing red icons with error and it is saying

> An error occurred during setup of Role Centers and Enterprise Portal.
>   Reason: Setup could not retrieve the Web application for Web site http://INFHYDCHROLUAT:1024. **The Web site is extended in SharePoint.**

Can anyone please address to the solutions to this error??

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the website on port 1024 is an extended website from another existing website. Try installing on the website on the default zone, and not another zone. In SharePoint you can extend an existing website and have it listening to a different port for different zones (intranet, extranet, etc).